# Is there a way of manipulating a global variable you use as an argument for a function in lua?

Tags: function, parameters, lua, arguments, global

I'm trying to write some code into a function so that it can be easily reused whereby a global value is increased.

The issue is that there are several different globals that can be manipulated, and I need the function to be able to handle each one.

I thought I could simply put the global variable into the argument in the function but it doesn't seem to work. Probably because lua creates a copy of the global variable it takes.

Is there a way to make sure that the global variable it manipulates is not just a copy?

I have already tried to make sure that all the relevant variables remain local, but the problem is that they are all in a loop, and so need to remain outside the loop to be able to increment properly.

Right now I have to write a separate function for each case of incrementation which is a little unweildy, if bareable.

Right now I have to do something like this

```lua
foo_time_1 = 0 

foo_time_2 = 0 
function foo_time_1(var) 

foo_time_1 += 2
 if foo_time < 2 then 
   sfx(02)
 end 
end

function foo_time_2(var)
 if foo_time_2 < 2 then 
  sfx(02) 
 end
end
```

This allows the code to run as intended, but Ideally I would like the code to look something like this:

```
foo_time = 0
foo_time_2 = 0

function foo_time_manipulator(global_var, len, sfx)

global_var += 2 
 if global_var < len then 
  play(sfx)
 end
end 

//so I can write

foo_time_manipulator(foo_time, 2, 02)
foo_time_manupulator(foo_time_2, 3, 02)
```

The problem with that is that the global variable doesn't change and so the sound effect loops continuously as every frame the function is re-read and it see that the global varaible remains at the value it was used as an argument, rather than the updated variable.

Sorry if this question has been poorly worded, it's a little difficult to articulate.

Is there any way in lua to be able to manipulate a global variable that is used as an argument?

A good qualifier may be that this code is being looped, and so requires an outside variable to act as a counter.

Comment: Consider using local variables and closures.

Comment: @lhf Yes, looks like I will have to do it that way for this particular project.

Comment: Answering the title question: No. Actual arguments are expressions evaluated to a value. An expression consisting of only a variable is a particular case with no special handling. The called function has no access to the expression evaluated to obtain the actual argument value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function foo_time_manipulator(global_var_name, len, six)
 local global_var = _G[global_var_name]
 global_var = global_var + 2 
 if global_var < len then 
  play(sfx)
 end
end
```

and use it like this

```
foo_time_manipulator("foo_time", 2, 02)
foo_time_manupulator("foo_time_2", 3, 02)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will give this a try. However I’m not sure if the Pico-8 engine allows for _G. That being said this will be very useful for some future projects I have in mind